# $a+b=3$ and $a^2+ b^2=7$. Find $a\cdot b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So we have $a+b=3$ and $a^2+ b^2=7$. I have to find $a\cdot b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a+b=3 \Rightarrow (a+b)^2 = 3^2 = 9 =a^2 + 2ab+ b^2 $$
Now since  $a^2 + b^2 =7$, $$(a^2+b^2)+2ab = 7+2ab = 9$$
You can solve this to obtain $ab=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $ab = \dfrac{(a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2)}{2}$

Comment: Very nice and elegant hint. +1

Answer (score 0):

$a^2 + b^2 = (a + b)^2 - 2ab$.

So you get : $ 7 = 3^2 - 2ab \Leftrightarrow 2ab = 2 \Leftrightarrow ab = 1 $

Answer (score 0):

Although above solutions are preferable, there is always the obvious approach of setting $a = 3 - b$, and then solve the polynomial.